# How do you add browserify to a yeoman project?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gruntjs, yeoman, browserify

I would like to use browserify instead of RequireJS for my Yeoman project. Can you please tell me how to swap this out so my app/ and test/ can take advantage of module.exports and require()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I did:

1. `npm install grunt-browserify --save-dev`
2. `npm install coffeeify --save-dev`
3. Add grunt-browserify step in `Gruntfile.js`:

   ```
   browserify: {
       basic: {
           src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js', '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.coffee'],
           options: {
               transform: ['coffeeify']
           },
           dest: '.tmp/scripts/application.js'
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add step to concurrent/watch steps, e.g.:

   ```
   concurrent: {
       server: [
           '...',
           'browserify'
       ],
       dist: [
           '...',
           'browserify'
       ]
   }

   watch: {
       coffee: {
           files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
           tasks: ['...', 'browserify']
       }
   }
   ```
5. Modify default app/index.html template, so usemin will concatenate and minify, from this:

   ```
   <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
   <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->

   <!-- build:js(.tmp) scripts/coffee.js -->
   <script src="scripts/hello.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

To this:

```
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/application.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Can you show this with the diff if someone were not using coffeescript?